# Printing objects from one class with another class Python

Tags: python, oop

I wrote a simple object oriented code with python. In first class named `A` I used `__str__` so that I can print my objects. In another class I put those objects in `obj_list`. My question is, why I can print my object with class `A`, but when I want to print as `print(my_object.obj_list)` I do not get string representation of my object?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):

        info = "My name is: " + self.name
        return info

obj_1 = A("Mike")
obj_2 = A("Jon")
obj_3 = A("Steve")

print(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj_list = [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3]


my_object = B()

print(my_object.obj_list)
```

Comment: Because `list.__str__` only uses the `__repr__` method of any objects *in* the string. If you want a different string representation of a list, you need to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding `__str()__` method, which called when something try to convert your class to string, i.g. `print()`. When you create a list of objects it put references of objects in the list and that's all. If you want them to be converted to string in any case, change:

```
def __str__(self):
```

to:

```
def __repr__(self):
```